# Calculate Tax from price displayed in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, calculated-field

I am trying to display the Price Including tax on a product page. The price is displayed in [OurPrice], so I would need to pull the displayed price (eg £0.95),times it by 1.2 and display the price in Pounds. Here is the code that i am trying to use, however, it doesnt display the calculated price. I would like to show it with the £ symbol in front of the number.

```
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
  <tbody><tr>
    <td class="retail-price" valign="top" nowrap="">[RetailPriceTitle]</td>
    <td width="100%">[RetailPrice]</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td class="our-price" valign="top" nowrap="">Our Price:</td>
    <td width="100%"><span id="op">[OurPrice]</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="incvat" valign="top" nowrap="">Inc Vat</td>
    <td class="incvat">

<script type="text/jscript">
var ours = document.getElementById("op").value;
  document.write (£(ours *1.2))

    </script>
</td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not syntactically valid javascript.  Try something like this:

```
var ourPrice = document.getElementById("op").innerHTML; // fetch the price
ourPrice = ourPrice.replace('£', ''); // remove pound character
ourPrice = parseFloat(ourPrice); // convert price from a string to a number
var incVat = ourPrice * 1.2; // calculate the price with tax
document.write('£' + incVat); // write the result
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RjWMK/

---

However, there are other issues with this code that are whole other topics in themselves and beyond the scope of this answer.  But as a research exercise:

1. Don't use `document.write()`. Instead run a script that find the value after the whole page loads, and then inserts the value into the content of the correct node.
2. Format the result properly using something like `number.toFixed(2)` or a currency formatting library.

Answer (score 0):

According to Alex answer, you need to put like this

```
<td width="100%">£10.0</td>
```

Comment: What alternative would there be to document.write()? And what code would I be using to find the value after the page loads?

Comment: @ShuliSampson, you can use JQuery  `$(document).ready(function(){ //get the value });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add to what Alex Wayne has already said.

I would take your JS code OUTSIDE the table cell block, and put it in the header before the  tag starts.  Then I'd take Alex's code and put it inside a "window.onload = function(){ //your code here }" block, so that it executes once the page has loaded.

And then instead of using "document.write()", I'd follow Alex's advice and replace the "document.write" line with a different line which will write the "incVat" value directly into the table cell.

Give a custom ID to the table cell where you want the value to be printed, like "incvatValue".

```
<td class="incvat" id="incvatValue"> </td>
```

Then, write this line of code:

```
document.getElementById("incvatValue").innerHTML = incVat;
```

When you're finished, your JS should look like this and it should not be inside the table cell:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var ourPrice = document.getElementById("op").innerHTML; // fetch the price
    ourPrice = ourPrice.replace('£', ''); // remove pound character
    ourPrice = parseFloat(ourPrice); // convert price from a string to a number
    var incVat = ourPrice * 1.2; // calculate the price with tax
    document.getElementById("incvatValue").innerHTML = incVat; // write the result
}
</script>

<td class="incvat" id="incvatValue"> </td>
```

BTW, you can replace "incvatValue" with whatever, just make sure the ID in the table cell matches with the ID being called in the JS.

Comment: Thanks for your help - It works if the script is <td width="100%">£10.0</td>, the moment i change it to <td width="100%">[OurPrice]</td> (Which is the code requires to pull and display the price from our database on the site), i get NaN....

Comment: In this case, if you know that the field will have "[OurPrice]", try inserting this line of code after the first line:  if (ourPrice == "[OurPrice]") { ourPrice = '0'; }